# Proving that a metric space $X$ is open and closed subset of itself.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space. Let $d$ be its distance function.

**Proving that $X$ is closed:** Complement of $X$ relative to $X=\emptyset$, which is an open set (as all points of an open set are interior points and $\emptyset$ is empty and therefore vacuously $\emptyset$ is open) and hence $X$ is closed.

I am having difficulty in proving openness part.

**Proving that $X$ is open:** Let $a\in X$, then for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, neighborhood of $a$ is defined as $N_\epsilon(a)=\{y\in X:d(a, y) \lt \epsilon\}$ 
How do I claim that an $\epsilon\gt 0$ exist such that $N_\epsilon (a) \subset X $?

**Edit:** The definitions of Open and closed sets, which I have used here (let $X$ be a metric space) :

1. **Open set:** $A\subseteq X$ is an open set if for every $a\in A$, there exists a  neighborhood $N_r(a) $ which lies completely in $A$ that is $N_r(a) \subset A$
2. **Closed set:** Complement of an open set in $X$

Comment: By the definition of $N_{\epsilon}(a)$ you are restricting yourself to elements of $X$

Comment: @JonathanHole: Please see my revised question.

Comment: Choose your favourite $\epsilon>0$. It will satisfy the definition trivially. (eg $\epsilon = 1$ works, or $\epsilon = 10^{10000000}$ will also work, or $\epsilon = 10^{-100000000000}$ also works). All of these work, because $N_{\epsilon}(a)$ is **by definition** a subset of $X$, so there's nothing to be proven.

Comment: What are your *definitions* of "open" and "closed"?  There are **many** different (though related) definitions which are used in various contexts.  Please edit your question to precisely state which definitions you are using.

Comment: You could do it by contradiction.  Assume there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $N_\varepsilon(a) \nsubseteq X$.  Then there exists some $b \in N_\varepsilon(a)$ such that $b \notin X$.  But $X$ is the whole space, which is a contradiction.  

Also, metric spaces endow a topology.  By definition of a topology, the whole space must be open.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I don't think you can choose any $\epsilon>0$ - there exist bounded metric spaces.

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis it doesn't matter. If $X=[0,1]$ with the usual metric, and $\epsilon = 10^{100}$, then $N_{\epsilon}(0.5) = [0,1]$ is the whole space.

Comment: @peek-a-boo you're right

Comment: The theorem doesn't require $X$ to be a metric, any space with a topology will do.

Comment: Clearly $N_\epsilon(x) \subset X$ for all $\epsilon,x$ and so $X$ is open. Since $X^C$ is vacuously open, the complement $X$ is closed.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: The problem I have is: Suppose we take a disk of radius $r$ centered at $x\in X$. What if there exists a $y$ in the disk such that $y\notin X$?

Comment: @Koro so what if that happens? You're trying to prove the entire disk lies inside $X$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: I meant $y\notin X$ in my comment.

Comment: By definition, $N_{\epsilon}(a)$ is the set of all $y\in X$ such that blablabla. So, by definition, the disk lies inside $X$; how is it possible for $y$ to be inside the disk and $y\notin X$? (Also, your definition of closed is wrong: it should be "A set $B\subset X$ whose complement is open")

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Is it because we are considering $X$ as universal set? Like I mentioned in title of this post--"X is open/closed subset of itself". Is it because of that that $N_\epsilon(a) $ is in $X$. If we had some $A\subset X$ then story would be different. I think I'm beginning to understand this now.

Comment: $N_{\epsilon}(a) \subseteq X$ because that's how it is defined (look at how you wrote the definition).

Comment: @peek-a-boo: I got it. Thanks a lot. Thanks a lot everyone for your support.

Comment: "a neighborhood of a is defined as $N_\epsilon(a)=\{\color{red}{y\in X}:d(a, y) \lt \epsilon\}$".  Note what I highlighted in red!  So $N_\epsilon(a)=\{\color{red}{y\in X}:d(a, y) \lt \epsilon\}\subset \{\color{red}{y\in X}\} = X$.  That's *all* there is to it!  *every* $\epsilon$ will be that $N_\epsilon(a)\subset X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in a space $X$, the space contains all the points to be considered.  There aren't any points *not* in the space $X$. So there aren't any points, limit points of $X$ or not, *not* in $X$ and every set whether an open neighborhood of a point $x$ or not is a subset of $X$.

If $X$ has any limit points or not, they are all in $X$ as there is nowhere else for them to be so $X$ is closed.

And for every point of $x\in X$ and *every* open neighborhood $B_r(x) = \{!!!!\color{blue}{y\in X}!!!!| d(x,y) < r\} \subset \{\color{blue}{y\in X}\} = X$.  So every point $x\in X$ is an interior point of $X$.  So $X$ is open.

.......

Oh, I see your definition of "closed" is *not*:  $A$ is closed if all the limit points of $A$ are elements of $A$;

but is instead:  $A$ is closed if it's complement is open.

Well, since $X^c = \emptyset$ we have to show $\emptyset$ is open.  Your definition of open is: for every $x \in \emptyset$ ..... something.  Well, since $\emptyset$ has *no* points and there are *no* $x \in \emptyset$ that is vacuously true.

So $\emptyset=X^c$ is open and $X$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I only have one doubt. How to prove existence of such an $\epsilon\gt 0$ such that $N_\epsilon (a)$ lies within $X$. It may so happen that $X$ is bounded or even worse consists of discreet points (finitely many, for example). I'm sorry if this is too obvious. I am very new to Metric spaces.

Comment: While asking this doubt, I am thinking of a set which is something like $S=\{(x,y)\mathbb R^2: 0.1\lt x^2+y^2\le 1\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$. Let $S$ be a metric space with usual metric. Then clearly $(0,0)$ is not an interior point. Hence, $S$ is not open in itself.

Comment: Or is it that since $X$ is a universal set. Each point that we consider lies within $X$ only. So there is no question of any $y\notin X$. In this case, yes $N_r(a)$ lies within $X$. But it's difficult to visualize, I guess.

Comment: Every $\epsilon$ is such that $N_{\epsilon}(a) \subset X$.  $X$ could have only one element and $\epsilon$ could be $10^{googol}$.  Then the $N_{10^{googol}}$ would, by definition be all ** the points $x$ is $X$** so that $d(x,a) < 10^{googol}$ and clearly all **the points $x$ in $X$** that do *anything are .... **in $X$**.

Comment: " But it's difficult to visualize, I guess."  It's intensely *EASY* to visualize.  $X$ is the *ENTIRE UNIVERSE*  there is ***!!!!!!!NOTHING!!!!!!!!!*** else.  Every point that is in $X$ is ..... **in $X$**.   Every subset of $X$.... is a subset of $X$.  A neighborhood is defined as  all the elements in $X$ that do something.  Read that again, read that a thousand times.  A neighboorhood is defined as *all the element in $X$* that .....  **all the elements in $X$ that** do something...  Well, if they are ***in $X$*** then .... THEY ARE IN $X$!!!!!!!!

Comment: In your example, (0,0) is of course an interior point.  Consider $N_{\epsilon}((0,0)) = \{x \in S| d(x,(0,0)) < \epsilon\}$.  For insance if $\epsilon = 0.00001$ then $N_{\epsilon}((0,0)) = \{(0,0)\}$.  Obviously $\{0,0\}\subset S$.  But is it true for all $\epsilon$?  Well, if $x \in N_{epsilon}((0,0))$ then $x \in S$ and $d(x,(0,0)) < \epsilon$.  And .... !!!!$x \in S$!!!!!.  So $N_{epsilon}((0,0))\subset S$.

Comment: To be an interior point there is no requirement that $N_{\epsilon} (a)$ contains any *other* point other than $a$.  But if $x \in N_{\epsilon}$ then $x \in X$ because $N_{\epsilon}$ is *BY DEFINITION* a subset of $X$.  You said what if $X$ were bounded or worse discreet... Okay, what if $X = \{5\}$.  Claim: every point of $X$ is an interior point. Pf: If $x$ is a point of $X$ then $x=5$. And every neighborhood $N_{r}(5)=\{x\in\{5\}|d(x,5)<r\}=\{5\}$. And $\{5\}\subset \{5\}$. So $5$ is an interior point of $\{5\}$.

Comment: We can even have $X = \emptyset$.  that if $x \in X$ then $N_{r}(x) = \{y\in \emptyset| d(x,y)<r\} = \emptyset \subset X$.  Not a problem.

Comment: There wouldn't even be a requirement that $N_r(a)$ is non-empty, except that $a\in N_r(a)$ so $N_r(a)$ can't be non-empty.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This case of singleton $X$ is what was bothering me. Resolved now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was also confusing definition of "limit point" with definition of "interior points". That's why this doubt. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I like the way how fleablood emphasizes the important parts.

Answer (score 2):

You give the definition yourself:

$$N_\varepsilon(a)=\{y\in X:d(a, y) \lt \epsilon\}$$

This set is **by definition** a subset of $X$ (because of the "$y \in X$" clause).
So just pick $\varepsilon =1$ (any positive number will do) and note that

$$a \in N_1(a) \subseteq X$$ as required.

Comment: I got confused between the definition of interior point and limit point so thought that $N_\epsilon (a) -\{a\}$ should be a subset of $ X$. But now I have understood that this $"-\{a\}"$ is not required. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, $N_{\epsilon}(a) -\{a\}\subset N_{\epsilon}(a)\subset X$.  Note $N_{\epsilon}(a) -\{a\}$ *could* be empty.  And empty sets are subsets of every set.